# AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding Encryption result different in PHP and Java

Tags: java, php, encryption, aes

I am developing a REST API in which the data to be passed to the server need to be encrypted with 'AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding'. The REST API client side is using Java to encrypt and decrypt the data, while on my side I am using PHP.

The secret key used here is hash with sha1. I have the same secret key value with the client side and also the IV value is the same, but when I try to encrypt and compare it to the client, it's different.

**JAVA Code:**

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.security.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.crypto.*;
import javax.crypto.spec.*;
import java.lang.Object;

class Main {

      public static String stringToHex(String base)
        {
         StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
         int intValue;
         for(int x = 0; x < base.length(); x++)
             {
             int cursor = 0;
             intValue = base.charAt(x);
             String binaryChar = new String(Integer.toBinaryString(base.charAt(x)));
             for(int i = 0; i < binaryChar.length(); i++)
                 {
                 if(binaryChar.charAt(i) == '1')
                     {
                     cursor += 1;
                 }
             }
             if((cursor % 2) > 0)
                 {
                 intValue += 128;
             }
             buffer.append(Integer.toHexString(intValue) + " ");
         }
         return buffer.toString();
      }

      public static String bytesToHex(byte[] a) {
       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(a.length * 2);
       for(byte b: a)
          sb.append(String.format("%02x", b));
       return sb.toString();
      } 

      public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnsupportedEncodingException,
        InvalidAlgorithmParameterException,
        NoSuchProviderException,
        NoSuchPaddingException,
        InvalidKeyException,
        IllegalBlockSizeException,
        BadPaddingException
        {
        MessageDigest sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
        String secretKey = "mysecretkey102018";
        String message = "00155001C"
        byte[] key = sha.digest(secretKey.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        byte[] value = message.getBytes();
        key = Arrays.copyOf(key, 16);

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
        IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA".getBytes("UTF-8"));
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keySpec, iv);
        System.out.println(bytesToHex(cipher.doFinal(value)));
      }
```

**PHP Code:**

```
class IDebit
{
    private $iv = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA";
    private $secret_key = "mysecretkey102018";
    private $message = "00155001C";        
    public function generateEncrytedKeyId()
    {
        $hashPassword = substr(hash("SHA1", $secret_key), 0, 32);
        $blocksize = mcrypt_get_block_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
        $str = $this->pkcs5_pad($message, $blocksize);
        $encrypted = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $hashPassword, $str, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, self::IV);
        return bin2hex($encrypted);
    }

    protected function pkcs5_pad($text, $blocksize)
    {
        $pad = $blocksize - (strlen($text) % $blocksize);
        return $text . str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);
    }
}
```

The encryption result on **Java** is `c1e7af770d9d0af59cc75d1c76aa78f6`, while on **PHP** is `d67a15a027be7e7ab68ea6ab88ea4f2f`

I'm wondering what is wrong with my code. I have googled and check on this forum about the question dozens of times but I am unable to get the same result. I have rechecked my code with the answers posted by people on this forum and it's identical.

Comment: Looks ok, just an idea - isn't the php code taking the hashPassword as a string? Imho you could decode the php with `pack()`. And for sake of readability, you could use some normal Hex utility instead of implementing all yourself

Comment: @gusto2 nope, the string is $str. $hashPassword is used as the key for encryption. I am not decoding in the PHP. Actually, both are encryption. I am given the encryption method in Java and I need to implement it in PHP.

Comment: 1. Don't use mcrypt, it's been deprecated for years.  2. Don't use a fixed IV.  If you do, you're opening yourself up to many of the same vulnerabilities as ECB mode + other CBC related ones.  3. Your ciphertext isn't authenticated.  It could be changed in transit and, when decrypted, will be invalid and you won't know.  4. Symmetric encryption makes no sense for transport security - anyone with the client-side code can decrypt any other clients messages.  That is silly.  The solution to this problem has been around for years and is far more straight forward to implement: **use HTTPS**.

Comment: 1. Openssl_encrypt doesn't give me any same result either. 2. Fixed IV is used because it is what the client does. I am connecting to a client web service in which is code based on Java and it's impossible for me to ask them to change it just for the sake of my usage. 3. Even before the ciphertext is transited, the result is already different. 4. Yes, I know that is going to happen, but luckily the information can't be encrypted without the correct secret key, in which isn't hardcoded actually. The code above is only the example, I suggest you try it out.

Comment: I think a rather naive understanding of cryptography is preventing you from understanding the rather serious flaws in your code.  If you're going to implement this, you should do so correctly.  Otherwise it's just a waste of time, there isn't any security.

Comment: I am still convinced the issue lies in the hex encoding of the key in php (as a key is used first 16 bytes of the hex representation). I may be wrong, I am not a php guy. However your Java example gives different output as for parameters provided, so nobody is able to test it. Or the difference lies in the magical hex encoding